# Jquery lag on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I've got a table with different columns identified with different classes.

I've also a checkbox binded to every column.

I created a function which is called on the click of any checkbox. In this function I hide/show the column which is linked to this.

It doesn't have any javascript error, and the code is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul input').click(function(){
            //alert('yooo');
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                //alert('checked');
                $("td."+replaceAll(" ","_",$(this).val())).show();
                $("th."+replaceAll(" ","_",$(this).val())).show();
                //alert($("td").length);
            }
            else{
                //alert('unselected');
                $("td."+replaceAll(" ","_",$(this).val())).hide();
                $("th."+replaceAll(" ","_",$(this).val())).hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

However, after every click, the action has a lag (after many clicks it becomes tooooooo slow, many seconds).

I tried also with .css instead of hide-show, but it doesn't make any change.

Comment: can you post your html too?

Comment: `<?
   $d=0;
   foreach($matriceCampi as $chiave=>$valore){
    ?>
     <tr id="<?=$nomi[$d]?>">
      <td class='nome_paziente' style="text-transform:capitalize;"><?=$nomi[$d++]?></td>
      <?
       $c=0;
       $index = 0;
       foreach($valore as $chiave2=>$valore2){
        if ($c == 0) {
         echo "<td> ".$date[$index++]."</td>";
        }
        ?>
        <td class="<?=(str_replace(" ", "_", $campi_questionario[$c++]->nome) )?>"><?=$valore2?></td>
        <?
       }
      ?>
      <!--<td class="<?=($campi_questionario[$c++]->nome)?>"></td>-->
     </tr>
    <?
   }
  ?>`

Comment: Ahm can you put the generated html it will be easier to interpret than the server side code.

Comment: it's too long, I can't make new lines ;(

Comment: `<table id="thetable" class="people_table">
   <thead class="header">
 <tr id="primariga">
  <th class="primacolonna nome_paziente">Paziente</th>
  <th class="primacolonna data">Data</td>
         <th class="primacolonna :)">:)</th>
<th class="primacolonna cancella" style="width:80px;"></th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
 </table>`

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" id="check0" value=":)" checked />          <span>:)</span>`

Comment: Please stop what you are doing. [Edit your question instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22487678/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I understood that the problem was linked only to checkbox, not on callback or on jquery function. I solved the problem simply by working with radio input, adding a "true" and a "false" radio input for every checkbox that was in the page.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of running the jQuery selector on every click like below:

```
    $("td."+replaceAll(" ","_",$(this).val()))
```

You could set up some sort of caching like:

```
    var cache = {} //<-- declare this outside your click handler

    //add the code below inside your click handler
    className = replaceAll(" ","_",$(this).val())
    if(!cache[className])
        cache[className ] = $("td."+className + ", th."+className); //select all the elements once and store in the cache object
    $el = cache[className];
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $el.show();
    else
        $el.hide();
```

Comment: I tried, the code works properly, even if it has the lag yet..;(

Comment: Do you have any documentation to back up your statement? This jsfiddle seems to prove that you can improve js performance by caching selectors: http://jsfiddle.net/youngjl1/D5UrB/